# Как определить цветное изображение или черно-белое?

Tags: java

Необходимо определять является ли изображение цветным или черно-белым. Стандартные средства (ColorModel, Color) отдают только цветовую маску.

Пришел к такому решению, проверяю разницу цветов и если она больше 5ти едениц, то изображение считаю цветным.

```
private boolean isColored(int pixel){
        int red   = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        int green = (pixel >>  8) & 0xff;
        int blue  = (pixel      ) & 0xff;
        return Math.abs(red - green) > 5 || Math.abs(red - blue) > 5 || Math.abs(blue - green) > 5;
    }
```

Может есть варианты получше?

Comment: А в чём проблема? Проверьте формат; если он допускает цвета, пробегитесь по пикселям. Двойной цикл, ничего экстраординарного. Если вы пользуетесь какими-то стандартными средствами, покажите код.

Comment: Пробежаться по пикселям тоже не проблема, а вот с определением цвета, я незнаю как быть, по идее оттенок серого, когда  r == g == b, но так может быть далеко не всегда. Мне бы наоборот хотелось бы найти библиотеку которая бы проверяла.

Comment: Ну, если у вас пиксели в RGB, то условие того, что пиксель не цветной, именно r == g == b. Если в RGBA, то r == g == b или a == 0. Или у вас есть контрпример? (Ну и неужели вы думаете, что библиотека будет делать что-то кардинально другое?)

Comment: То есть если у вас что-то экзотическое, типа HSV, то надо проверять v == 0 || s == 0.

Comment: Моя задача, посчитать стоимость печати, на входе я получаю pdf, выбираю из него изображения, а так как изображения растровые, то не всегда получается, что серое именно r == g == b, хотя выглядит как серое, никакой экзотики. Я думал, что библиотека будет уметь определять отклонение от нормы серого (r==g==b), я до этого с цветом не работал, поэтому могу не знать, каких-то особенностей.

Comment: Ну, библиотека не знает же, какой у вас в голове критерий. Придумать общее решение для всех возможных случаев невозможно (а ваш конкретно случай достаточно экзотический). Так что ваш код по идее должен быть правильным. (Но не забудьте ещё `alpha`, при маленьких `alpha` пиксель прозрачный, и значит практически белый.)